# Run inside of an if statement

Tags: java

First of all, I'm pretty new to Java (About a week) and I'm a little bit confused with some stuff, basically I'm trying to see if a boolean is equal to true then start a thread, so here is my code (btw I am using two classes)

```
package apackage;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Threads2 {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String selection;
        System.out.println("Input one of the following answers for which timer you would like to start:");
        System.out.println("Dragon, Baron, RedBuffNeutral, BlueBuffNeutral, RedBuffEnemy & BlueBuffEnemy");

        selection = scanner.next();
        if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("dragon")){
            boolean dragon = true;
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Threads("Dragon", "THREAD1"));
            t1.start();
        }else if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("baron")){
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Threads("Baron", "THREAD2"));
            t2.start();
        }else if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("redbuffneutral")){
            Thread t3 = new Thread(new Threads("Red Buff Neutral", "THREAD3"));
            t3.start();
        }else if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("bluebuffneutral")){
            Thread t4 = new Thread(new Threads("Blue Buff Neutral", "THREAD4"));
            t4.start();
        }else if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("redbuffenemy")){
            Thread t5 = new Thread(new Threads("Red Buff Enemy", "THREAD5"));
            t5.start();
        }else if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("bluebuffenemy")){
            Thread t6 = new Thread(new Threads("Blue Buff Enemy", "THREAD6"));
            t6.start();
        }else{
            System.out.println("You inputted an incorrect answer, please choose from the following next time:");
            System.out.println("Dragon, Baron, RedBuffNeutral, BlueBuffNeutral, RedBuffEnemy & BlueBuffEnemy");
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
package apackage;
import java.util.Random;

public class Threads implements Runnable{
    String name;
    String text;
    int time = 999;
    int RedBuffNeutral, BlueBuffNeutral, RedBuffEnemy, BlueBuffEnemy = 300000;
    int Dragon = 360000;
    int Baron = 420000;
    Random r = new Random();

    public Threads(String x, String z){
        text = z;
        name = x;
    }

    if (dragon = true) 
        public void run(){

            try{
                System.out.printf("%s is dead for %d\n", name, Dragon);
                Thread.sleep(Dragon);
                System.out.printf("%s has respawned!\n", name);
            }catch(InterruptedException exception){
                System.out.printf("An error has occured in %s", name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am having no problems with the first class, it's when it actually comes to running the threads is when I get the problem, I really have no clue how to do it and the error occurs on the 16th line of the second class, it says: Syntax error on token "if", invalid AnnotationName
Any help would be appreciated and if you would like more info on my problem just ask! Thanks :D

Comment: `if dragon = true` , that is an assignment , not a conditional

Comment: The problematic if statement is also appears to be outside of the scope of any method in the class.

Comment: I don't see where `dragon` is declared, I think there may be other bugs

Answer (score 3):

`=` is the assignment operator. The equality operator is `==`, so, your code should read:

```
if (dragon == true)
```

Better yet, since `dragon` is a `boolean`, it can be evaluated directly:

```
if (dragon)
```

Comment: Well thanks for the help, so I tried this out but it still get's the same error! Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

One of the errors is your use of the `=` assignment operator to test equality. Instead, use the `==` operator.

```
if (dragon == true)
```

However, you get the same result if you simply test the boolean value itself:

```
 if ( dragon )
```

Answer (score 2):

By your original code, I thought the if condition should be

```
if(Dragon == 360000){
```

If you indeed wanted it be a boolean, it would be a better way naming it "isDragon" to put it in the if condition.

And one more thing, by Java naming convention you should have your local variable named with first character be lowercased.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [semantic error](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwci.llnl.gov%2Fcodes%2Fbasis%2Fmanual%2Fnode53.html&ei=06ohVLe9DdWcygT7rYHQDg&usg=AFQjCNFGo0EbX7Bu0PMouPseOsMs6Sk3fQ&sig2=aRrd5xlryzcbQeRFF_kepA&bvm=bv.75775273,d.aWw) here :

```
if (dragon = true) 
     public void run(){ /* etc */
```

You don't mean to say what you think here: you are assigning true to dragon var , and it's always true after.

You must use

```
if (dragon == true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your post for easier readability. Note the else-if statement, it saves you from having to indent your code too much and makes it more readable.

However, you're calling the variable in your Threads class which does not exist in that class. Also your if-statement should have the format mentioned by @AndyThomas, but you can also not have an if statement by itself. It needs to be within a method or a constructor. It should look something like this:

```
package apackage;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Threads2 {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String selection;
        System.out.println("Input one of the following answers for which timer you would like to start:");
        System.out.println("Dragon, Baron, RedBuffNeutral, BlueBuffNeutral, RedBuffEnemy & BlueBuffEnemy");

        boolean dragon = false;
        selection = scanner.next();
        if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("dragon")){
            dragon = true;
            new Threads(dragon, "Dragon", "THREAD1");
        }else if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("baron")){
            new Threads(dragon, "Baron", "THREAD2");
        }else if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("redbuffneutral")){
            new Threads(dragon, "Red Buff Neutral", "THREAD3");
        }else if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("bluebuffneutral")){
            new Threads(dragon, "Blue Buff Neutral", "THREAD4");
        }else if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("redbuffenemy")){
            new Threads(dragon, "Red Buff Enemy", "THREAD5");
        }else if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("bluebuffenemy")){
            new Threads(dragon, "Blue Buff Enemy", "THREAD6");
        }else{
            System.out.println("You inputted an incorrect answer, please choose from the following next time:");
            System.out.println("Dragon, Baron, RedBuffNeutral, BlueBuffNeutral, RedBuffEnemy & BlueBuffEnemy");
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
package apackage;
import java.util.Random;

public class Threads implements Runnable{

    String name;
    String text;
    int time = 999;
    int RedBuffNeutral, BlueBuffNeutral, RedBuffEnemy, BlueBuffEnemy = 300000;
    int Dragon = 360000;
    int Baron = 420000;
    Random r = new Random();

    public Threads(boolean dragon, String x, String z){
        text = z;
        name = x;
        if (dragon == true) {
            run();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            System.out.printf("%s is dead for %d\n", name, Dragon);
            Thread.sleep(Dragon);
            System.out.printf("%s has respawned!\n", name);
        }catch(InterruptedException exception){
            System.out.printf("An error has occured in %s", name);
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tried this code, but it makes more sense. Let me know how it goes :)